# In Angular, is the suffix 'Change' on an event emitter doing something special internally

Tags: angular

I am not sure if I'm having a mental warp here or if I just learned something new.

I have a component that has the following input and output.

```
  @Input() open: boolean = false;
  @Output() openChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

In the code I have:

```
  toggle(e) {
    this.open = !this.open;
    this.openChange.emit(this.open)

  }
```

Now, In my parent component, I can successfully use two-way data binding to the component:

`<app-foo [(open)]="value"> Is Open: {{open}}`

This has me scratching my head.  If I change the output to be something like this

```
 @Output() openChangeX = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
//...
    this.openChangeX.emit(this.open)
```

or even

```
 @Output() openXChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
//...
    this.openXChange.emit(this.open)
```

The two-way data binding no longer works. All I did was change the name. Does adding "Change" to a matching input varaible do something internally in Angular that allows this. I can not find any documentation on this.  I also removed the `this.openChange.emit(this.open)` line and replaced it with `this.cd.detectChanges()` wondering if the event was forcing a reread of the `open` variable. No luck.

It appears to me that varx and varxChange cause some type of relationship that I was unaware of.  Any clarification would be greatly appreciated, even just a pointer to an existing doc I have overlooked.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#how-two-way-binding-works

Answer (score 4):

After looking into this I finally found this article.

https://medium.com/@preethi.s/angular-custom-two-way-data-binding-3e618309d6c7

So yes, it appears that adding "Change" does have an impact.

> The magic here is the suffix ‘Change’ in the event’s name
> amountChange. If the property binding name is ‘x’, the event binding
> name should be exactly ‘xChange’. Only then angular recognizes
> banana-in-a-box [()] syntax.